# Nhibernate "could not initialize a collection"

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, orm, mapping

I have a following problem with my NHibernate One-to-many mappings. If I want to get all Customers, by my API methods, I get a following error:

> "$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The
>   'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'text/html;
>   charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"$id":"2","Message":"An
>   error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"could not initialize a
>   collection: [Designet.Models.Customer.Orders#1][SQL: SELECT
>   orders0_.CustomerId as Custom2_2_1_, orders0_.Id as Id1_2_1_,
>   orders0_.Id as Id1_2_0_, orders0_.CustomerId as Custom2_2_0_,
>   orders0_.Description as Descri3_2_0_, orders0_.Price as Price4_2_0_,
>   orders0_.Created as Create5_2_0_, orders0_.Deadline as Deadli6_2_0_
>   FROM Order orders0_ WHERE
>   orders0_.CustomerId=?]","ExceptionType":"NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException","StackTrace":"
>   w NHibernate.Loader.Loader.LoadCollection(ISessionImplementor session,
>   Object id, IType type)\r\n

Underneath I pasted my codes. I was looking for answer for my problem on google and SO, but nothing, what people proposed, helped. I don't understand which part of code throw an error. Maybe you have some proposition, what should I do, to solve the problem? I will very glad for your help.

Customer model:

```
public class Customer
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        public Customer()
        {
            Orders = new List<Order>();
        }
    }
```

Customer Mappings:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true"
                   assembly="Designet" namespace="Designet.Models">
  <class name="Customer" table="Customer" dynamic-update="true" lazy="true" >
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="Id" column="Id" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    <bag name="Orders" lazy="true" inverse="true" >
      <key column="CustomerId"/>
      <one-to-many class="Designet.Models.Order"/>
    </bag>    
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Customer Database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer] (
    [Id]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Order Model:

```
 public class Order
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Deadline { get; set; }

        public virtual int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    }
```

Order Mappings:

```
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true"
                   assembly="Designet" namespace="Designet.Models"
    <class name="Order" table="Order" dynamic-update="true" lazy="true" > 
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="Id" column="Id" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="Customer" column="CustomerId"/>

    <property name="Description" />
    <property name="Price" />
    <property name="Created" />
    <property name="Deadline" />
    <property name="CustomerId" not-null="true" />

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Order Database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order] (
    [Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Price]       SMALLMONEY     NULL,
    [Created]     DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [Deadline]    DATETIME       NULL,
    [CustomerId]  INT            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([CustomerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([Id])
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner exception from your comment json link write `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.` Your table is named `Order`, which is a SQL keyword. It must be escaped. Use back tilt for this.

```
<class name="Order" table="`Order`" ...
```

**Notes for mapping semantic correctness:**
A `bag` should be mapped as an `ICollection<>` rather than an `IList<>`. An `IList<>` is for mapping a `list`: a collection in which each element have an index recorded in database, from zero to collection size minus one, without any hole. It is very unlikely you wish that.

Moreover with your model, you should use a `set` instead of a `bag`: a `bag` allows duplicates. Your model does not allow them, an order may appear only once in a customer orders collection. If you change for a `set`, use an `ISet<>` in code.

**Notes on your question**
Your error message is truncated and does not allow to check what is the cause of your trouble. The `GenericADOException` is supposed to contain another `InnerException`, but the message you have provided does not show it.

Please get the complete exception message, and please try to post it in a readable manner: "pretty print" your JSON, or better yet, get the exception `.ToString()` output.

Comment: I've changed `bag` to `set`, and `IList<>` to `ISet<>`, but it didn't help. There is a full error: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=48b540615c2550df97c1cafdb3550502

Comment: And it contains the answer to your trouble. Answer edited.